# How to ignore safearea when presenting a sheet?

Tags: swiftui

On devices that have a home indicator (e.g. iPhone 15 Pro), the safe area is being added at the bottom.  That displays fine but when the keyboard appears, it's throwing out the view and it appears as though the safeareainset is being divided between the top and bottom of the view (see screenshots).  I've made the background yellow to easily see the white padding that is being added.  I've tried all sorts of combinations of `ignoresSafeArea()` and can't get the right solution which is to have no additional padding.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestSheetHeight: View {
    
    @State var showCard: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            showCard.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Text("Show the Card")
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $showCard, content: {
            CardView()
        })
        
    }
}


struct CardView: View {
    
    @State var height: CGFloat = 0
    @State var textField: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Line A")
            Text("Line B")
            Text("Line C")
            TextField(text: $textField) {
                Text("Test")
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .background {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Color.yellow
                    .onChange(of: geometry.size) {
                        height = geometry.size.height
                    }
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
        }
        .presentationDetents([.height(height)])
    }
}
```

[image: iPhone SE without keyboard]
[image: iPhone SE with keyboard]

[image: iPhone 15 Pro without keyboard]

[image: iPhone 15 Pro with keyboard]

Comment: Can you explain what each of the screenshots is demonstrating? The second one looks like your desired result if I understand correctly. How did you achieve that?

Comment: Sorry, I named them but isn’t showing up. 

Screenshots 1 & 2 are an iPhone SE with and without keyboard showing. Screenshots 3 & 4 are an iPhone 15 Pro with and without keyboard showing. In screenshot 3, there’s a safe area inset due to home bar but in screenshot 4, that safe area inset isn’t needed. You’ll see it’s then diving that safe area inset and adding it above and below the yellow view.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this CardView implementation. Unfortunately, I don't have an explanation for why setting this inside the background works incorrectly.

```
struct CardView: View {
    @State var height: CGFloat = 0
    @State var textField: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.yellow.ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Text("Line A")
                Text("Line B")
                Text("Line C")
                TextField(text: $textField) {
                    Text("Test")
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .background {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Color.clear
                        .onChange(of: geometry.size) {
                            height = geometry.size.height
                        }
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                }
            }
            .presentationDetents([.height(height)])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that solution doesn't actually get rid of the extra padding on top and bottom once the keyboard is showing.  Add a modifier to the VStack ```.border(.blue)``` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I see .presentationBackground(.clear) in your example resolve part of problem you can check is sufficient for you